# OpenTelemetry Java agent extension to add Spring authenticated User id in Span attributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, open-telemetry, javaagents

I have a Spring Boot 2.7.5 application running with an `opentelemetry-javaagent.jar` that includes some custom extensions. I now want to add a custom `SpanProcessor` that adds an attribute `userId` to all Spans corresponding to incoming HTTP Requests to the Spring REST API.
How can I do that?

In Spring I would get the authenticated user's id/information with:

```java
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

But can I access the Spring Security Context from within the `SpanProcessor` in my javaagent?

I tried finding an example of a otel-javaagent extension accessing any Spring Beans but could not find any yet.

Answer (score 1):

OpenTelemetry Java agent extensions live in the isolated `AgentClassLoader` which is why they don't have access to Spring classes.

I'd suggest:

- Add the `userId` to the SERVER span at the beginning of the request

  - (as a side note, this seems like it would be a nice addition to the OpenTelemetry auto-instrumentation, since there's already an OpenTelemetry attribute to store it in [`enduser.id`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/trace/semantic_conventions/span-general.md#general-identity-attributes))
- In your SpanProcessor, copy the `userId` down from parent to child, e.g.

  ```
  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public void onStart(Context parentContext, ReadWriteSpan span) {
    Span parentSpan = Span.fromContextOrNull(parentContext);
    if (!(parentSpan instanceof ReadableSpan)) {
      return;
    }
    ReadableSpan parentReadableSpan = (ReadableSpan) parentSpan;

    ...
  }
  ```